# How can I create an OPML file from a large RSS feed list?

Tags: xml, rss, opml

I have this very large (tens of thousands) list of rss feeds for different websites. And I want to make an OPML file out of all of them, so that I can import it into a feedreader software.

I found plenty of web tools that'll make an OPML file out of a list of feeds, but my list is just too big.

I've searched around everywhere for a solution.

I have absolutely no clue about this kind of stuff, I'd appreciate it if somebody could help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What format is your list in now?

You say it is big, how big? How many feeds?

Comment: It's just a large text file list that looks like this: website.com/external?type=rss2

Comment: On each line that is

Comment: And there are over 100,000 lines of them.